# Modest proposal: How about paying employees to review?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been progressively less active over the years, and like so many others, I gave up curating as a Sisyphean task ages ago.

Popping back in here recently I see that the debate is *still* raging, and apparently is no closer to resolution.

I would suggest that Stack Exchange pays employees to man the review queues on Stack Overflow for several months. It seems to me that this would be a double incentive (financial, and mental health of employees) to find viable solutions to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend moderating as a mental health improvement technique :)

Comment: @ivarni if you're allowed to skip Meta you should be all good ...

Comment: Is that *pay* just a fixed salary or is that target driven: *number of flags handled, suspensions handed out, chat rooms frozen*. That could be fun ....

Comment: @ivarni, I meant that the company would be motivated to fix the problem because they'd save money, and the employees would be motivated to fix the problem because otherwise it would drive them mad. But maybe your :) indicates you understood that.

Comment: Will 'inducements' be allowed?   How much, (USD), would it cost to have the PHP room suspended?

Comment: [dogfooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)?

Comment: @yivi, I don't know if it matters. The point is that as long as there are people cleaning up the sh*t for free, the company has no incentive to fix the problem. So I guess this suggestion is a corollary of the moderator strike.

Comment: @yivi https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented, sorry I was sloppy and said moderator instead of reviewer. Corrected in title and body of question.

Comment: Maybe $5 for a 100 reviews?

Comment: An [old quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/#answer-285903): *Most of the professionals who are here come here to contribute and to help others, not to spend all of their time sweeping the floor.* Requiring less floor-sweeping by experts could go a long way towards improving relations.

Comment: This should be a duplicate, because the idea is surely not new, but I can't find one.

Comment: @Trilarion, that's what I thought too.

Comment: I see no reason to close and to downvote this question. The answer is clear (review works also as community control, i.e. it helps to create such a site what is liked by the programmers of the world around. It can be done correctly if also the content is decided by the programmers of the world around.) Making the concepts of it is a good idea, the closure/downvote and likely deletion of this question is... well... *maybe a little bit suboptimal*.

Comment: @peterh downvotes on `feature-request`s mean something different, as you know by now. I agree that there's no reason to close or delete the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey but disagreement with proposals is clearly non welcoming :)

Comment: @peterh voting works different on meta, and are often used to express disagreement. Those votes do not affect reputation in any way.

Comment: I added the feature request tag, but only because it is one and the question was downvoted already before. In this case, it's especially useful to look at the pluses and minuses separately. It seems that about 40% of the people like the idea and that's a lot. Maybe for feature requests one should not display U-D which is not very informative but rather U/(U+D)  (U=#upvotes and D=#downvotes).

Comment: @peterh Not sure about evil, but parts of it seem a bit on the edge

Comment: @peterh there's a lack of rationality in certain parts of the community, that's for sure

Comment: @Trilarion I believe, the tagging had only little effect to the score of the question, and the attitude of the community was the major determinant.

Answer (score 7):

The voluntary review activity is indeed slowly declining (from around 40k close votes per month in 2015 to 30-35k close votes per month in 2019) while the question asking activity roughly stays constant. In total, the voluntary review activity is not sufficient to clear the close review queue, there is probably much more work that could be done.

Money is an important and usually effective incentive to do such work. The idea is not bad and part of the advertisement revenue could go directly into paying people to do reviews. If you pay per review and implement quality checks, you even should get impartial, somewhat high quality review results.

Possible pitfalls could be that the amount of payment required to achieve the necessary work could just be too much for the benefit or that the voluntary workers could increase their expectations of compensation, seeing that others are getting paid. If the company would start paying reviewers it could hardly go back after some time without some kind of backlash. It's not sure, that the review quality of paid reviews would actually be high enough.

Alternatives would be to filter or handle the bad content in another way using some kind of automatic systems (if and when they are available). Or we just live with the current state of basically cleaning up only a little bit relying on voluntary work.

As a summary: The company will make a calculation and probably decide that the risk and costs are currently not worth the benefit. It's a valid approach to the problem though.

Comment: RE the declining close votes, anecdotally, I've seen some (read: a lot of) dreadful questions during the last couple days in `php` and so many of them had no close votes but 10-25 views. It's a little crushing especially since the required close votes have been reduced down to 3 yet closures don't seem to be taking place.

Comment: September is coming and the experiment ends in a week. We are in for a rude awakening, @Script.

Comment: speaking of alternatives, it is worth to mention one that has proven to work well in LQ review, where regular reviewers are sort of "backed up" by diamond moderators. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388318/839601) is a proposal how to adjust such approach for close review

Comment: @gnat I guess this feature request would then naturally extend to pay moderators for their work.

Comment: @Trilarion I doubt it, they do LQ reviews without pay, why close  reviews  would differ

Comment: @gnat You're right, although the transition is probably gradual. At some point there might not be enough candidates for the job anymore.

Comment: I don't think answer actually relates to the question - hiring random people to do reviews is very different than forcing your company to dogfood own product...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Question doesn't say that the whole company must use the review system. Just that employees should be paid for it. Doesn't have to be all of them. On the other hand, this answer doesn't say that you should hire random people. Hire the right people instead.