# Close vote number changed?

Tags: discussion

Has the number of close votes needed to close a question changed again? It seems to have gone back from 3 to 4? I thought 3 was pretty good.

Comment: This is a remarkable failure of the "Featured on Meta" feature.  Ought to be food for thought, perhaps users just stop looking at it when it never changes.

Comment: It only went back yesteray @Carcigenicate, so you didn't miss it, really :-)

Answer (score 14):

It was a 30 day experiment:

[Experiment: closing and reopening happens at 3 votes for the next 30 days (ENDED)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-days-ended)

The 30 days are over so it reverts back to 5 votes (less if you're a gold badge holder casting a duplicate vote). The results will be analysed and we'll hopefully get the result soon*.

A number of people have expressed the opinion that they thought the 3 votes were better, but we'll have to wait and see.

* hopefully not 6-8 weeks.

Comment: You state that the results will be analyzed, but I have to wonder what metric will be used to decide the utility of the hypothesis. How exactly are you deciding on whether 3 vs 5 close-votes is good for the site or not?

Comment: @Hovercraft I'm not doing the analysis so I don't know what criteria are being used. You'd need to ask an employee.

Comment: Shog9 apparently, based on his recent edit of the linked question.