# What to do in a situation where my question is voted closed by someone and then re-asked by that person later

Tags: discussion

Earlier, I asked a question, see it here:
*[How to create a persistent framebuffer in cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385066/how-to-create-a-persistent-framebuffer-in-cuda)*

The first edit was rough and was missing code. So, I took a day to write code from scratch that:

- wouldn't give away proprietary code
- would still compile to the same degree of success and failure as original code
- (while writing this version, I found the answer and then posted that as the answer)

I then posted that code as an edit on the original question. While taking the time to edit and produce code that other people can look at, I get harassing comments that do not address the technical aspects I'm discussing. I ask for clarification on how said commenter would address the problem while noting that their critiques do not address the question being asked.

Then, question is voted off topic by the commenter. After being voted off topic, the commenter then re-asks my original question (*[Persistent buffers in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544633/persistent-buffers-in-cuda)*). By this time, despite my attempts to edit the original question, the commenter has voted to close my question so that I can't even keep it open.

Anyone who wishes this site to be supportive of newer members, or respectful of reputation/points, what can I do about this?

Comment: I don't see why you think you need to do anything. Your question got closed and deleted, meaning no one else can answer your question anymore. Then one of the closers/deleters posted a boiled down version of your question with an answer to it. They also say that it was in response of your now deleted question.  Doesn't this provide the thing you wanted: an answer to your problem? I really don't see the issue here. (I can't argue about the correctness of the other question/answer, because I have no idea about CUDA)

Comment: No. I had already answered my problem and posted that to original question, as mentioned in this question.

Comment: Your question even after editing is too convoluted and long. Answer as well. The other user clearly explained what is wrong with your question and the answer. Since your question was closed (rightfully) and it was not in good shape for reopening, he posted another more focused and helpful Q/A for broader audience. The fact he was inspired by your question is irrelevant here.

Comment: @yivi... Thanks for your insight on the matter and for addressing the question at hand. I still disagree with the handling of the original post but am far less perturbed knowing that commenter took steps that would not bolster their reputation while actively me keeping me from improving mine.  As it happens, the answer in the community wiki still does not address my original question. I can easily take it up there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, please consider that for the question to be deleted, it had to be close-voted by 5 different users, and then 3 users with over 20k would have had to cast delete votes.

So I wouldn't focus so much on this single user: this is not a **one** person closing, deleting and then posting.

As far as one of those users posting another question similar to yours (which I can't see, since users with less than 10k can't see deleted posts), it does look to me like their intent was to help, not hinder you.

They tried to distil what they thought was a better quality question from yours, and posted an answer that could help you and other visitors. They even linked to your question, so everything is out in the open (I imagine they linked to it before it was deleted, since the link to a now deleted question is less useful).

Additionally, they posted the answer as a [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). So they **gain no reputation** from any votes to that answer, and they are indicating anyone is welcome to contribute with edits to that answer.

Beyond that, if you arrived to your own independent solution, and you believe it could be posted under the new question, you could also do that as well so it helps future visitors.

Comment: "it had to be close-voted by 5 different users" - it seems this happened during the [3 close-vote experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day).

Comment: @npo since the question was deleted when I was answering, and this question was asked after the experiment ended; I assumed. Still; it makes no difference to the import of the answer, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your clarity of thought

Answer (score 9):

Next time, do what you did *first*. It's called a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you should *have* one when you ask a question. Because only when you do that, your problem is well enough defined. Otherwise you will get a lot of guesswork as an answer and that wastes your time and the other people's time.

You might even find your answer without asking and get better at finding answers in the process.

A question at Stack Overflow should be the *last* option to solve a problem, not the first. Only if all else fails that you could do yourself, it makes sense to post a question.

Comment: Yup. Point taken. Which is why I edited my question originally. However, what is there to do about a question I have edited properly, that is still closed and then re-asked by one of the people that closed it - despite my editing for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any evidence of malice or misconduct. This is a related question, not an identical one. Also, the OP makes that fact that this is a related question clear from the outset, so there's no dishonesty.

Also, they posted an answer to the question (as Community Wiki, no less, which is further proof that they weren't acting maliciously because they don't get reputation points on the answer); did the answer help you? If so, is it actually that important that they posted the question instead of you? On the other hand, if the answer did not help you, feel free to comment to that effect and/or downvote.

**TL;DR** There was no dishonesty or attempt to game the reputation system, and you got an answer to the question out of it. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: The question given was not one relevant to the original question. It was specifically an answer about why not to do what I was asking to do. However, the technology maker explicitly makes open a code path to do what I was asking about - hence my question. Therefore, the answer given is irrelevant as it argues against the tech I was pursuing. Ie. It was an answer of "don't do it your way. Do it my way." Or... Arguing the process instead of addressing the technology in question.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not necessarily saying that that's the case here, but FWIW sometimes "don't do that" *is* the correct answer. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) With that said, if you found the answer unhelpful or inaccurate feel free to comment and/or downvote it, but the fact that you think that the answer is wrong or irrelevant isn't proof of misconduct.