# I'm trying to be polite to this user, but it doesn't seem to be helping. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, rude-or-abusive, unfriendly-or-unkind

I recently tried to explain to a user that their answer couldn't be correct because the question wasn't complete yet:

> [image]
>
> [image]

However, the user seemed to take this personally and started saying somewhat things like "You're genuinely pathetic". I then tried to politely apologize and explain to them what was wrong with the question and that the question had been (partially) fixed (at that point). At that point, my answer (coincidence?) received a downvote.

I've flagged these comments as "unkind", but I can't flag for a moderator's attention (flag ban) to explain this.

Here's the comment I made on the original post:

> [image: Please read up on creating a minimal reproducible example.]

Later, another comment was posted on my answer:

[image: Don't ever delete my comments. And if you're going to comment on my posts, then own up to it. Like I said, you're genuinely pathetic.]

I don't think what I did was wrong.

What should I do?

Comment: You flag the offending comment and move on. Don't further engage the user.

Comment: I don't know... It seems like I haven't done enough to help the user who was saying these things about me.

Comment: To help whom? In what way? Let the moderators handle it as your primary objective at this stage is to disengage, pure and simple

Comment: I sort of wanted to help them fix their answer... but if they're not going to listen, I guess there's not much I can do.

Comment: They have already shown that their mindset won't absorb any help at all. Again the only thing to do is to disengage.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tried that, see edit. I'll keep trying, though. Soon enough it should stop.

Comment: No, you're not trying that -- You're replying to them, and to disengage, you **don't**. Walk away. Delete the page. Don't respond to comments. If they comment and you don't reply, they lose the motivation to post more comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So... delete the answer?

Comment: There's no reason to delete your answer, JL2210. I understand it's unpleasant to receive those types of comments, but please don't let that stop you from providing useful content to the site. If they keep leaving comments like that, continue as you did and flag their comments - comment flags still go to moderators.

Comment: Pro tip: from the moment you receive a blatantly offensive comment, that's when the line's been irremediably crossed. Even so, there were so many times I wished I had refrained from commenting even sooner. Commenting is a darned game of roulette without enough rewards to be worth playing.

Comment: A case of [xkcd 386](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/386:_Duty_Calls)?

Comment: This is not a help desk. Don't be motivated by "wanting to help". Be motivated by "wanting to provide a high quality answer to a high quality question".

Comment: @Raedwald Do you understand how hard that is? It's hard enough providing a high quality answer, let alone a high quality answer to a question instead of a person. The reward I get at the end of the day is from "I helped someone", not "I posted multiple high quality answers".

Comment: Posting high quality answers is *how* you help. You help not just the person that asked - but also everyone that comes along in the future with the same issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Stating that the answer does not solve the problem, without explaining *why* it does not solve the problem, is only going to cause problems.

**Strongly avoid commenting on your downvotes.**

If you *do* feel the urge to comment on a downvote, make sure that there is something concrete to contribute. Even then, use caution.

Comment: I just... want to give people a chance to improve. I know how it feels when people downvote my answers without explanation, and I don't want other people to feel that way.

Comment: I hate that I agree with this. You're damned if you do, and you're damned if you don't. People want comments, but in my experience, far too many people also get toxic when they actually receive a comment on a downvote. If they don't receive comments, it's "awful no one comments" and that's perceived as toxic by the user. Optimally, comments would be used as a way to improve, not necessarily just for the receiver, but also for the commenter (everyone can make mistakes).

Comment: @JL2210 Yeah, every single time I've commented on a DV I've been made to regret it later. If you strongly wish to leave a comment I would suggest doing it and then waiting for a response before potentially downvoting. There's a slight chance they'll not get upset right away and maybe take your comment to heart. But usually when faced between the choice of DV and/or comment I find it best to just pick one of them.

Comment: "*Strongly avoid commenting on your downvotes.*" which is the opposite of what the system suggests... which makes downvoting answers so frustrating. Some times I even just put a comment under an answer because I don't think it's bad enough to downvote but can be improved or has some inaccuracy. Yet by the time I finish the comment, somebody else downvoted the answer and occasionally that leads the answerer to think I'm "the bad guy" who downvoted.

Comment: @JL2210 downvote without comment. Vote to close questions that are unclear. The tooltips on both provide plenty of context for the OP and the user to improve if they're interested. Otherwise, they still help the site via quality control. When you comment your downvote and engage like this, you make yourself vulnerable.

Comment: I am in a different boat - I kind of want people to comment on a downvote. The way that they phrase that comment is not only one of the few bits of information available to see if actually explaining what can be improved will not backfire because you can read the tone - but it allows me to lie through my teeth and open that explanation with "Well I did not downvote, but..."

Comment: Yet again I say: users say they want  comments to explain downvotes, right up to the point when they actually get them.

Comment: Pro-tip: If you downvote and see a comment which reads: "Why the heck was my answer downvoted ?", don't reply.

Comment: I regard refraining from commenting on your downvote solely because you don't want to risk a poor reaction as an abdication of duty. If you have other reasons, that's fine, but that shouldn't be one of them. Even if it's poorly received at the moment, it's entirely possible for someone to learn from it later. It is much better to share information than it is to withhold it, though arguing over it is rarely productive, of course.

Comment: For that matter, don't leave a critical comment on an answer that's been downvoted if you are the only other answerer to the question, even if the downvote wasn't yours, or even if *you upvoted it*. You will be scapegoated. The kind of person who would react this way to your critical comment that happens to be associated with a downvote you cast will react the same way even if the downvote wasn't yours.

Comment: @Zoe Not exclusive to Stack Exchange. I've had more than one *irl face to face conversation* where someone asked "what were you thinking?" and I explain and their response boils down to "Yeah, I don't actually care what you were thinking." Do not, ever, under any circumstance, explain your thought process to another human being. ***Especially*** if they ask.

Answer (score 26):

I'm not sure what anyone here thought would happen.

The main thing we're told when we're closing questions is that it's to *prevent* incomplete or bad answers.

The problem with this circumstance is, if a question isn't closed in time to prevent answers, we have this gap to quickly seal up; a bad question got an answer and so we feel obliged to step in and explain why this is a bad question and why it shouldn't be answered.

Oof.

Ultimately, the circumstance could've been prevented if you had

## never commented on your downvote

and kept your close vote on the question to yourself.

I can understand wanting to help, and I have on many an occasion commented on why I downvoted something.  However, I only really saved that for something that I could demonstrate was factually wrong in the answer, and I started to refrain from explaining procedural downvotes.  If your only gripe with the answer is that the *question* was incomplete...it isn't worth a comment at all.

It might not even be worth the downvote if it's got a semblance of being correct, but I'm not here to judge that.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389207/10795151

Comment: @JL2210:  Well, it ain't back yet, is it?!

Comment: although I didn't specifically state that I voted to close the question; good inference.

Comment: It'd be pretty silly to complain about someone answering an incomplete question if you yourself didn't do everything in your power (that is, close voting it) to prevent it...