# We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold from 5 to 3 for good

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

It’s my birthday today and I’ve got a gift for you.  **We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold on Stack Overflow from 5 to 3**.

About a month ago, Shog shared the [results of our experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) testing this lower close/reopen threshold. From that, we observed that closing, reopening, and editing all became more efficient, so we deemed the test to be successful.

At that time we said that we’d consider moving the threshold back down to 3 following the end of our [testing period for the new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow). The new post notices, which Yaakov has recently rolled out across
 Stack Overflow (the rest of the network and Teams coming very soon), are also part of our efforts to make experiences around curation less frustrating and more helpful for everyone. Because we feel the new post notices provide better feedback to guide authors of closed questions, we’re comfortable re-lowering the close/reopen threshold again. Permanently. For now.

We’ve still got a long way to go towards improving how feedback happens in this part of the system. Our goal is to improve the way our system helps users share and receive feedback. Thank you for your input as we work on more incremental improvements.

Comment: Happy birthday!

Comment: This is "for good", and it is. Is there something you're planning on doing "for bad"? :-)

Comment: Many happy returns! :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Questions were worth 10 points. Then 5. Now we're back to 10. Everything is permanent until it isn't

Comment: @Makyen "For good" as in "permanently".

Comment: Happy Birthday! And thanks for the early christmas gift :)

Comment: I prefer to think that it can also be interpreted as "[for great justice](https://encyclopediadramatica.rs/For_great_justice)", @Makyen...

Comment: is it considered to be kept only for SO? so that other sites will have threshold 5

Comment: Other sites can have [whatever threshold is most appropriate for them](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/cancelling-election-lets-try-something-else-testing-three-vote-question-clos), @gnat

Comment: Thank you! I'm eager to learn what the next steps will be in improving feedback, but slow and steady I guess. I also appreciate the direct communication surrounding this change.

Comment: Not for nothing, but levity is not in vogue on meta sites anymore, even for staff members.  But thanks for the voting change anyway.  One of the most positive things I've seen happen on SE in awhile.

Comment: @MeganRisdal Yeah, my comment was intended as a pun, but didn't end up working all that well.

Comment: I'm confused.  This seems like a good change, and I'm not used to those lately.

Comment: This is great! I'm guessing this means Shog's musings on requiring a consensus of 2 or 3 votes (up to a cap of 5 total votes as (previously) always) to close a question a bit quicker than normal will not be implemented, then?

Comment: @TylerH We're still considering it.

Comment: We got a lot of good feedback on that idea, @TylerH - I think we can do better than what I proposed without a lot of extra work. But that'll have to wait for a new year...

Comment: That's very nice. Now it's kind of rewarding again to close vote. It's still work and maybe even with 3 close votes not enough questions can be closed but definitely more than before.

Comment: What happens to questions that currently have 3 CVs? Do they get auto-closed, or is a 4th CV required?

Comment: @pault They require another close vote.

Comment: Finally we are no longer living in sin, for on the matter of close votes it is written: "three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out."

Comment: @JeroenMostert ::enthusiastic clapping::

Comment: Will this eventually apply on posts which currently have 3-4 close votes currently sitting on them? They seem to be still open..

Comment: @wim No; they'll need an additional vote to put them over the edge.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/ Ohhhh and Happy Birthday Megan and thanks a lot for your work Shog and all the others involved!

Comment: Thanks for this - I wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: @MeganRisdal Can you tell me how to start this process for the Arduino SE?

Comment: My concern with 3 vote closing was that it became more likely for questions to be close voted by people with little or no expertise at all with the question's tags. Has any analysis of that scenario been done? Of course you don't always need to be a SME to know when a poor question should be closed. But anecdotally, I saw questions being closed during the trial period because they allegedly weren't clear, when it was blindingly obvious what the poster was asking if you truly understood the question.

Comment: @VE7JRO Open a discussion on your meta site about what you'd like the number to be (either 1 or 3 or 5) and once you've talked it through, ping me in the TL and I'll get a one-month test started.

Comment: For once, a Stack Overflow Company meta post that has more than 0 votes!

Comment: Happy Birthday. Should we be concerned about keeping you away from Rings of Power?

Comment: @skomisa That issue is addressed by *everyone* having edit rights. If you see a question closed as unclear that is perfectly obvious to you, given your expertise in the subject, then you should **edit it**, clarifying to others what is clear to you. That'll then allow the question to be reopened (and reopening is easier, too, since the same vote count threshold applies to reopening as it does to closing).

Comment: Obviously any change like this has pros/cons, but overall I think this change will prove to be a significant improvement to stackoverflow. And happy birthday, Megan!

Comment: Why not split the difference and set it to 4?

Comment: Lowering it to 3. Am curious if this increases the likelihood of posts getting closed due to low quality moderations.

Comment: @JamesWong-ReinstateMonica the same amount that gets reopened for the same causes.

Comment: Shouldn't the threshold be set to 3 on MSO as well? It currently looks like to not be the case, for example [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391961/im-not-even-allowed-to-comment-on-my-own-questions) required 5 votes to be closed.

Comment: A step in the right direction, but the experiment's results showed that it's still not enough to handle all the incoming review items. So [my (re)quest for further efficiency improvements ideas for which have crystallized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented) remains. <sub>(And I'm still on the strike.)</sub>

Comment: I don't see this as a good change for the most part; considering SO suffers from trigger happy close voters, all this does is make it easier for them to close a question.

Comment: It seems like a positive change in SO! Finally, we are reducing the boundaries! For very a considerable time, this was a positive change in the right direction. Maybe in the future, there could be a possibility to extend it to other Stack sites. Not to all or maybe there should be a team that could discuss it with the internal moderators of each area.

Comment: As an ordinary user this disappoints me.  Finding productive discussions which were cut off by close votes is already a frequent and frustrating experience for users.  I understand that SO is more about curating questions than appealing to the masses, but these sorts of decisions tend to piss off more people (do most users even have accounts?) than I believe most moderators realize.

Comment: @AlexJansen - If you see a category of question being closed that believe would be productive to have at Stack Overflow, perhaps start a discussion on what the impact would be of allowing those.

Comment: @AlexJansen StackOverflow is not for discussions, it is **only** for well defined programing question and direct answers to the questions.

Comment: I bet that even if u have lowered d threshold to just ONE vote, it wud hv still given u positive results, BECAUSE..where is the place for other side of the story here? What or Where can the questioner appeal against? Is there a process/way in which the questioner can put forth his/her counter arguments against the closing? The closing process here is pure dictatorial. With no place for beginners, this site has become BY THE ELITES, OF THE ELITES and FOR THE ELITES! And for the same reason it's bound to doom. Elites can do much but can't think like a beginner and THAT has it's own unique value.

Comment: @amsquareb The appeal process is the same as it's always been: you edit the question, following the provided guidance, to ensure that it conforms to our requirements for questions. This edit then places the question into a review queue, where 5 (now 3) votes will re-open it.

Comment: @CodyGray That is exactly what I meant by dictatorial - you HAVE TO edit, you have no choice.

Comment: Uh, yeah. This is a moderated, curated website, @amsquareb, not the Wild West. We have requirements.

Comment: @CodyGray You are getting me wrong. My point is, what is the significance of any 'test', when you have no 'appeal' process, and the decisions of mods are final? Who is to say and check if they are abusing their power or taking wrong decisions? Why am I being imposed a 'decision' without getting a chance to put forward my case? Bdw, there is a thing called civilization and democracy in between the 'Wild West' and 'Dictatorship' - those two aren't the only options u know.

Answer (score 279):

This is a step in a positive direction.  Thanks for making this Permanent™.

Comment: Yes, it's permanent, for now.

Comment: Yea we needed some happy news, it has been a while.

Comment: Happy to see this change as well. It seems that [some of the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), however, still needs to be updated. As I'm writing this, that page states "It takes 5 close votes from members..."

Comment: Why do you think this is positive? Closed questions still appear on the home page, so it doesn't help with signal:noise. And close reasons are applied inconsistently. All closing seems to do is annoy people who are hoping to get their question answered.

Comment: Why was it 5 in the first place? And won't the new threshold make it easier to abuse?

Answer (score 74):

I think this is a good step forward. While I still think [we need to actively revisit the close reason set and wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337064/178816), making questions get actioned faster helps everyone.

A primary source of contention between members of the community is a result of [the friction caused by the closure process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366956/content-rules-and-perceptions).

> Would you rather come back to your post and see a bunch of canned comments, some upvoted multiple times, or would you rather the system guide you through issues with your post, and notes that it's not going to get visibility beyond being linked on your profile until you make at least one edit (with links to help)? The latter is definitely preferable, and offers far less opportunity for folks to speak out of frustration. - [Tim Post ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371438/1026459)

[5 votes can take quite some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/178816), and as a result the time frame became troubling because users tapping their feet waiting for closure often left canned comments which the askers then lashed out at.

Hopefully this change reduces that friction point, any progress there will improve community health.

Comment: We have some cool stuff in the pipeline continuing on this theme that I hope we can tease soon. :) Thanks for this feedback!

Comment: @MeganRisdal - Awesome :) Definitely exciting to see some of these projects moving forward!

Comment: I don't understand that friction. Why would you sit around waiting for the Question to be closed? Why give canned responses instead of genuinely trying to help? Or, if you don't have time, why not just move on, and wait for the closure to happen? Why actually be there waiting for it to happen?

Comment: Solution: [Don't leave comments on posts you downvoted or voted to close.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389558/10795151) (just realized that you're the same person that told me that)

Comment: @trlkly - Fully agree. However, there are users who do that. Many of them are convinced it helps even though I rarely, if ever, see any positive reaction to their canned comments. There is even a whole chat room that coordinates such activity (SOCVR).

Comment: @JL2210 - Yeah, I did say that :) Although someone else would have as well. Commenting on questions which are in the process of closure rarely helps. Answers can be a different story sometimes.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, if you ask the user politely to fix their question they usually give an effort.

Comment: @JL2210 - Unfortunately sometimes there is no amount of fixing that can be done. Misconceptions about the platform lead to users asking questions, which even if they are formed perfectly, are simply off topic. At times, it is possible that a polite inquiry results in improvements, but that requires the asker to actually be present (sometimes they are not so attentive).

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, but in other cases it can be fixed, as in the case of a missing MCVE.

Comment: @TravisJ Your experience with comments prior to close appears significantly different than mine. I've found that leaving a comment, primarily canned comments, that point out what needs to be improved in the question is usually helpful and often gets a positive response from the OP (i.e. the question is often improved prior to closure). Perhaps the primary issue is the comment content, rather than a general statement about the results of the leaving comments. Note: I agree there are a significant number of comments which end up negative for the OP, but that's mostly due to the comment content.

Comment: @Makyen - If I leave a comment, it is personalized and only in the case where it is clear the asker is attentive. That route is highly effective. What I have observed in the past decade from canned comments though is thousands of times where absolutely nothing positive happens, mostly from prolific canned comment users. Canned comment content is not really helpful, and is constantly being revised with outlook to leave an actual customized message. In that same regard, "what have you tried" is permanently banned from comments unless it is actually descriptive of the issue.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree there are a number of comments similar to "what have you tried" which are rarely, if ever, helpful. Such a comment doesn't provide the OP with any actionable information/direction which would allow them to improve their question. However, I'd argue that the issue is the content of the comment, not the fact that it's a canned comment, or that it's not personalized. While, yes, a personalized comment is often better, there's an important trade-off to be made between the time that requires and the number of questions which are posted on SO.

Comment: @Makyen - Not taking the time to invest in the question is the problem with canned comments. If users are not interested in investing time, then there is no point in them posting any sort of comment. Especially in today's environment where the tooling now allows for simply actioning the post and having that result in actual closure; users not interested in becoming involved should just action the post and move on. Let the system handle the messaging and process for users fixing questions.

Comment: @TravisJ I partially agree with that, but also disagree. For example, in the tags I frequent, I can provide a canned comment that explains what's needed in ~95% of the cases where the user hasn't provided enough information for a MCVE/MRE. Explaining the things actually needed is significantly superior to the stock close reason for MRE, which doesn't explain what's actually needed to reproduce problems in those tags. Sometimes, that comment needs to be modified to the situation, but most of the time, it's fine just as a canned comment, and often gets OPs to edit in enough info for a MCVE/MRE.

Comment: Ultimately, it would be nice if enough people were moderating so each question could have individual attention. Reality is that there's way too many questions compared to the time available from the number of people who are moderating. If the comment is actually helpful, then it's better to have it, regardless of if it is canned or personalized. If the comment isn't helpful (e.g. primarily a way for the commenter to express frustration) then it's better not to have it. But, again, that comes down to the content of the comment, not, directly, if it was personalized to the specific question/OP.

Comment: @Makyen - I would assume the percent of times the OP actually edits the post after the canned comment is rather low. It would also be slightly inflated by situations where the OP edited the post with disregard to the canned comment. From inspection, there is also a strong correlation between posting a canned comment and also being a close voter for closed posts. Just because a canned comment can explain something generically doesn't mean that it will be successful, even if the content in the canned comment is informative.

Comment: @trlkly "Why give canned responses instead of genuinely trying to help?" Sometimes the system adds the canned response itself. For example if you identify the question as a duplicate. Personally I hate being associated with a comment I didn't write.

Answer (score 42):

Shog9 had concerns about reaching consensus in the experiment write up when we only used 3 votes:

> Oh, right... That no-consensus thing went up by a thousand percent. We should, uh, probably fix that.

Is this something that is going to be tackled at a later date?

Comment: Got some good ideas on that in the last thread, so hope to work on a slightly more useful solution in the new year.

Comment: We’ll just put every split decision into a review queue. That’ll solve all our problems.

Comment: *Cody Gray: Alignment change LG -> LE*

Comment: @CodyGray A Close Vote Triage?

Comment: Oh, good point, @JL2210! We need to *triage* the priority of those split decisions first, *then* we'll dump them into a Contested Close Vote Review Queue. Note that the process may be recursive, depending on the outcome of the CCVRQ task.

Comment: @CodyGray How did you find our secret plans?

Comment: @MeganRisdal Shog let the unicorns out of their cages, and they faxed out a flash drive containing confidential Stack Overflow documents. This was part of the More Queues More Metrics initiative, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @CodyGray then the cvq will be replaced with the consensus queue.  Then that one will fill up instead. That doesn't seem like a good solution to me, but that could just be me.

Comment: @Chipster Sometimes my sarcasm lands, sometimes it doesn't. I find it's most humorous when it's close to the truth, but also more likely to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @CodyGray *gasp* But sarcasm is unwelcoming...

Comment: @jpmc26 Here, a survival kit, it's not much, but you'll need it out there in the exiles' wastelands.

Answer (score 27):

Yay! I think I speak for a lot of us when I say this will be greatly appreciated. The previous experiment showed moderation will be more effective now--and that benefits everyone.

Oh, and also happy birthday. Weird you're *giving us* a present on *your birthday*, but I'll take it.

Comment: Pippi wound and wound and seemed to forget everything else. But suddenly
she remembered something. "Oh, my goodness, you must have your birthday
presents too!" she said.
"But it isn't our birthday," said Tommy and Annika.
Pippi stared at them in amazement. "No, but it's my birthday, isn't it? And so I
can give birthday presents too, can't I? Or does it say in your schoolbooks that
such a thing can't be done? Is it something to do with that old pluttifikation that
makes it impossible?"
- The timeless classic Pippi Longstocking by Astrid Lindgren

Comment: Well, Hobbits on their own birthday give presents to others... just saying...

Comment: I think Megan's present is getting to post a change that doesn't deserve to be downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 17):

**Finally!** ⭐️✅

---

I hoped for this ever since experiment results were published. I understand that you wanted to wait for the new post notices, but personally I don't see much difference between new and old post notices.

Main source of frustration when the question is closed came from the fact question is closed not from the post notice itself. New post notices, just like the old ones are not self explanatory (IMO old ones actually contained more useful information than new ones) and OP still needs to follow the link and do a whole a lot of reading to understand why was question closed.

For increasing the question quality and lowering the frustration of both question askers and users with moderating powers, you still need to address educating users about site before they even attempt to ask question and during the question asking process.

There is still way too many book, technology, library and similar recommendation questions asked. Way too many do my work for me questions, and debug my code questions that don't include minimal reproducible examples.

Answer (score 14):

Is this only for stackoverflow or also for the other stackexchange sites?

For politics, skeptics, and similar sites often dealing with subjective topics this will probably have a bad effect.. even with the 5-vote requirement there are too many ideologically motivated closings, when people want to remove legitimate questions because they think they (or the answers given) don't support their views... and therefore there are lots of generic *"not clear what you're asking"* close votes even if the OP explained exceptionally when what is being asked.

Comment: It is only for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you.  The high vote threshold, combined with close votes aging out, was why I stopped going through the close vote queue every day - too often I found that a question that, say, three people had decided needed to be closed, took too long to get any additional votes and so it would return to open status; it's frustrating to do a bunch of janitorial work and see it get entirely discarded.  There's probably some additional work to be done on that front (how often are questions that were voted to close and aged out nominated for closure again? I'm curious if they can have reduced vote thresholds the second time) but this at least should help.

Although there's also plenty of other meta drama that's preventing me, personally, from being terribly active in any sort of janitorial way.

Answer (score 9):

Permanently. *For now.*

#oxymoron

On a serious note, thank you for this. As I said after the initial trial:

> **Please bring this back.**
>
> This change helped questions be closed, fixed, and reopened at a faster pace than usual. For that reason, I'd like this to be brought back (at least for a little while). If it's not asking too much, I'd also like this to be made permanent.

Well, that's exactly what you did. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) :)

Answer (score -12):

I do not believe that it is a good idea to give all users the same weight in the voting criteria. While only needing 3 closing-votes is an excellent way to quickly close questions, I do believe that users with more reputation in the question's tags should have more weight into this decision. A notice that questions are now very quickly closed, and sometimes maybe too quickly.

To this end, I would propose a weighted system based on the badges. Call it an extended version of the [Golden hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers):

> **Rules for closing a question:** A question gets closed when the total votes accumulate ***5*** voting points.. Each *voting user*, gets *n* voting points assigned to its vote. The total voting-points per voting user are assigned in the following way:
>
> - **3 voting-points**: the voting user has minimum one golden badge for any of the question-tags
> - **2 voting-points:** the voting user has minimum one silver badge and no golden badge for any of the question tags
> - **1 voting-point:** this is the default case if the voting user does not have any silver or golden badges related to the tags assigned to the question

With this method, you would need between 2 and 5 votes to close a question

> - **2 votes:** 2 gold votes
> - **2 votes:** 1 gold and 1 silver vote
> - **3 votes:** 1 gold and 2 default
> - **3 votes:** 3 silver
> - **3 votes:** 2  silver and 1 default
> - **4 votes:** 1 silver and 3 default
> - **5 votes:** 5 default

Just an idea.

It also gives some more meaning to those badges.

Furthermore, when you introduce offsets to the type of "close-vote", you could mimic the golden hammer within the following way. Duplicate votes start with 2 voting points, the question gets now closed as a duplicate when 3 more voting-points are obtained:

> - **1 vote:** 1 gold vote (*ze hamma*)
> - **2 votes:** 2 silver votes
> - **2 votes:** 1 silver and 1 default
> - **3 votes:** 3 default

Comment: Similar things have been proposed before. I’m sure this would work well for larger tags, but for the little tags this would suck. For questions tagged [tag:octave] you have exactly one user with a silver badge, there are no golds. This tag also gets less views, so collecting 5 votes on a question has always been impossible. With the 3 vote limit we can finally close questions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for pointing this out. I did not think of that.  As I said, it was only a suggestion. One can of course always find methods to fix this, but it would just overcomplicate everything and I prefer the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score -25):

Reopening has always been much  harder and less frequent than closing. 
This change accelerates closing, including many wrong ones, but doesn't help with reopening proportionally. Wrongful closing always causes damages, even when reopening can happen under much rarer cases.

Closing, downvoting and deleting has long been abused by some users.
This site has already gone too far to alienate many people, and encourage mistreatments, abuses and bullies. Yet,  think the move is "for good", maybe just for a few but certainly not for the suppressed and many many that have reduced participation or quit this site to avoid toxicity.

Ideas like this that come from a few who live in their own bubbles and are either outsiders or confidently don't need to ask questions are disastrous. 
How about coming up with some real changes to combat mistreatments, abuses and bullies? That will indeed be for good.

Comment: Reopening also only takes 3 votes now. Also note that they did test this change before deciding to make it permanent.

Comment: Seems you missed my first and last paragraphs. Consider how   the "test" was designed, evaluated, and by whom? Are they living in their bubbles?

Comment: No, I read the first paragraph, which implied you didn’t know that the number of required reopen votes also changed and I also read the last paragraph, which implied you didn’t know they tested first. If you think the number of reopen votes should be even lower and that the test is poorly designed and evaluated, that should be in your answer. It’s not clear that’s what you’re taking issue with, it reads more like you weren’t aware of everything that was done.

Comment: I’m not trying to be insulting: I honestly thought you didn’t know about those changes. Your answer will be clearer if you explain what should have happened with the experiment and the number of close votes.

Comment: The reason that reopening is less frequent than closing is that it is rarely appropriate to reopen. The reasons are twofold: (1) contrary to your assertions, the overwhelming majority of closures are correct, so there is nothing to reverse, and (2) it is unusual for the asker to manage to edit their closed question into something that is suitably on-topic. There are a variety of reasons for the latter, but the big one is that most closed questions are *fundamentally* unsuitable for Stack Overflow, such that no amount of editing is going to savage them.

Comment: Your observations match my experience. Finding 3 members with reopen privilege in order to reopen an improved question, or a question that that was wrongly closed, is hard work. People shouldn't have to jump over hurdles in order to be allowed to post an answer that will help someone and will hurt nobody.