# -1 votes are needed to reopen this question

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen

Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135421/1015495) question, with 4 votes to reopen at time of writing:

[image: -1 more votes are needed to view this image]

The title text claims -1 more votes are needed to reopen the question. I would guess that it's related to the close/reopen threshold being [lowered from 5 to 3 yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/1015495). Either that or I *really* don't understand something about how close/reopen votes work.

Comment: You got that right. This may be a valid bug, but it will disappear magically as soon as all close and reopen votes from before the change expire, so it's not really an issue.

Comment: M'aiq *would* come to us with tales of negative votes needed to open a question...

Comment: @TylerH there are some that say you need negative votes to reopen a question. There are some that say Mike is a liar. You shouldn't believe either of those things.

Comment: it's simple isn't it, -1 reopen vote = 1 vote Leave Closed. As soon as reviewer willing to reopen clicks Leave Closed, math will do the magic and question will be reopened. I think

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you don't understand how these votes work, these [votes age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/178816).

**Close votes, reopen votes, and flags all age away after 14 days from the last vote/flag *unless* the post has 100 views in which case it is 4 days**.

While technically a bug, there is no real point patching this. Going forward, there will be no possible way for reopen votes (or close votes) to surpass their limit.

If the question highlighted here had 100 views, then it would have been quicker, but it is at 72, so the 14 day limit applies.

Broadly, this also means this "bug" has a maximum shelf life from today of 12 days and is not worth altering.

Comment: I'll be mildly amused if the question reopens itself once a vote ages away