# Where did Megan Risdal's diamond go?

Tags: discussion

I clicked on the [We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold from 5 to 3 for good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832), and was surprised that the author didn't have a diamond anymore.

Do we have information about that? Do we have a MetaSE or MetaSO post on the subject?

Comment: Now I'm honored to have my own Meta SO post. :P

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Megan Risdal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8157789/megan-risdal) left the company to return to the Kaggle team at Google.

She has not retained her diamond because she was not a community-elected moderator before being hired by Stack Overflow.

See [her blog](https://mrisdal.github.io/blog/posts/reflections-on-stack-overflow/) for more details, including reflections on her time at Stack Overflow and future plans.

The good news is, she does plan to stick around and continue contributing to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Ho "rejoining the Kaggle team at Google.". Upvoting  your answer is my only way to Say gratz without a twitter account. So if you happend to read this comment that one is for you. "Congratulation, and best luck in journey"

Comment: @xdt Pinged her on the Twitter. Maybe she wants to come by and say leave some farewell words on this question.

Comment: All the best for her. Kaggle sounds great. "The team focused on public Q&A is shockingly small: four IC developers." I didn't know that. That doesn't sound so great.

Comment: I'm really sorry to see her go... If one were to ping her in chat, her account would get a notification?

Comment: @Cindy I think so, she was active yesterday in chat. I saw her popping by in the meta room on her last day, but I didn't know that back then. I'm sad to see her go as well.

Comment: Thank you for the well wishes! I don't have much more than that to say (my blog post was pretty long, eh?). :)

Comment: @MeganRisdal Long, insightful and informative - I read every word and may go back and read it, again :-)

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister. I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: I remember that it was one of the first things that really seemed odd about the network, that I constantly created new accounts on each sub site. I got used to it over time, but not only from a maintenance perspectiva but also from a user experience point of view one can ask if this really necessary.

Comment: @Trilarion I think you may have  accidentally posted that comment on the wrong answer. It has no obvious relevance to this discussion about Megan's departure.

Comment: @CodyGray The connection is her legacy blog post. In that she describes the amount of maintenance effort it takes to have per site profiles and proposes to unify them.

Comment: Maybe another last nitpicking, because this is the only place to discuss the blog post and it seems to be not really true. Wikipedia also isn't made up of facts frozen in time. Also Wikipedia is a living, evolving library. In the blog post however StackOverflow is contrasted to Wikipedia in that regard. I just mention it, because otherwise the blog post is really great and a big source of inspiration to me.

Comment: @Trilarion You are in luck! It seems that you can use Twitter to discuss Megan's blog post on GitHub, which discusses Stack Overflow, contrasting it against Wikipedia. For good measure, you might also want to share your tweets on Facebook, since there weren't quite enough sites involved yet.