# improve website's way of working and language

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

just saw a question being "closed" by three individuals. The first individual is sufficient to make the point.

Use "Solved" and "Already solved" instead of "closed" or "associated with an already answered question". No one wants to "lose" anything.

I feel this was a setup, where the question asked did not appear in the prior search before asking. The question was well ranked with over 70 votes.

The names and picture of one of the users left a feeling of annoyance. Please ensure people use their real names and pictures when talking to people.

Thank you and Please Fix this.

Comment: I agree that names of close voters are pretty insignificant, it could be hidden behind a collapsible for all I care.

Comment: I wonder if this question could be a case of a misunderstanding of the expression "closed" on Stack Overflow. I see a ton of comments over there stating "accept this answer to mark the question as closed". It seems like a lot of users believe "closed" means "answered". This might be the case here.

Comment: @ModusTollens Maybe, though the accept text doesn't make any mention of the word "closed" for me.  For quick reference: "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)".

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica You are right. It would be interesting to find out _why_ many users associate "closed" with "answered". My guess: they notice "closed" banners on question that happen to have an answer and wrongly associate one with the other.

Comment: @ModusTollens could also be a more "traditional" forum mentality. Normally, you'd post a question (you'd have a bunch of posts misunderstanding it) and get an answer that resolves it. When that happens, the question is usually marked "SOLVED" (the word is appended to the title) and the thread is closed. So solving = closing on a lot of other places on the World Wide Web.

Comment: why does it annoy you if someone is called foo and their picture is of a cat if they provide a well-structured answer/question? SO is a content and quality first website - not a social media platform

Comment: "*Please ensure people use their real names and pictures when talking to people.*"  **No**, just no.

Comment: As someone who doesn't make any particular effort to hide who I am, I still disagree greatly that anyone should ever be required to expose themselves.  It invites harassment outside the site.

Comment: @Trilarion In an ideal implementation OP would never have seen the names of the close voters; it'd've been hidden behind a 3k rep privilege, if only they implemented the new banners the way we asked...

Comment: @Rahul Unfortunately, Stack Overflow's on-site search is very poor at finding duplicates, unless you know the ends and outs of how to tweak it. It's been that way for years, with *many* issues/meta questions about it. I believe that, if the person asking does search, the poor on-site search capability is the primary reason they don't find obvious duplicates. I strongly recommend you use an off-site search engine to look for questions relating to your issues (e.g. you can use [this Google search to search just Stack Overflow](//www.google.com/advanced_search?as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com)).

Answer (score 14):

> Use "Solved" and "Already solved" instead of "closed" or "associated with an already answered question". No one wants to "lose" anything.

[Closure of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) is entirely unrelated to whether the question has been answered/solved. Questions get closed because they do not meet our requirements—they are off-topic, missing information, and/or are unclear. While questions are closed, they do not accept answers.

Questions that have been answered/solved are indicated by the asker of the question assigning a green checkmark to the answer that they felt was *most helpful* in solving their problem. This is called ["accepting" an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). New answers can *always* be posted on questions, even if an answer has been accepted. This is because someone might come along later and know of an *even better* solution than was originally accepted.

Neither one of these is a permanent state. If a closed question is edited to resolve the issues with it, it can be re-opened. If the asker thinks a new answer provides a better solution, they can change the accepted answer checkmark from the old answer to the new answer.

> I feel this was a setup, where the question asked did not appear in the prior search before asking.

If a question has been asked before, it is a *duplicate*, and so we associate it with the previously-asked question. This is done for two reasons: (1) to help the asker get an answer faster, and (2) to keep the answers consolidated in one place.

Marking a question as a duplicate is often still referred to as "closing" the question, since, like closed questions, duplicate questions do not accept answers. But the *reason* for closing the question is quite different: a duplicate question may be perfectly valid and on-topic for Stack Overflow, it just happens to have been asked before.

An [off-topic or unsuitable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) will be closed, regardless of whether or not it has been asked before.

> The question was well ranked with over 70 votes.

A question's score is not relevant either to it being a duplicate or it getting closed. We have established criteria for what types of questions [are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and what types of questions are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on Stack Overflow. Questions that are not suitable for this site will be closed, regardless of how many votes they have received.

(Note that, due to the incredibly large volume of questions that Stack Overflow receives per day, some unsuitable/off-topic questions get missed and aren't closed. This does not prove anything regarding their suitability. It just means they got missed. If you see such a question, please feel free to flag it as needing to be closed.)

> The names and picture of one of the users left a feeling of annoyance. Please ensure people use their real names and pictures when talking to people.

I can understand how someone choosing to remain anonymous might leave you feeling annoyed, but it has been a fundamental tenet of this site since the very beginning that you are *not* required to use your real name. User names are not even required to be unique (in other words, there may be 20 different people who go by "Jon").

This isn't Facebook; Stack Overflow is not a social network. The name of a user really doesn't matter. The only thing we care about here is *content*, and that's what we evaluate—when upvoting, when downvoting, when voting to close, and everywhere else. The identity of users is not important.

Comment: Cody, This only invites "junk" AI tactics. Real People answer questions, Hiding does not hide anything. Again, you have'nt answered the first point. Let me repeat, "just saw a question being "closed" by three individuals. The first individual is sufficient to make the point."

Comment: @RahulChoudhary That's frankly insulting; I use a fake name because there are unfortunate people out there who will target you for reasons that aren't sane.  I've answered plenty of questions under this alias; that it is an alias doesn't devalue the quality of my answers a single bit.

Comment: @Rahul Regarding the "AI"/"Real People" argument, I refer you to [this XKCD cartoon](https://xkcd.com/810/), which makes the point far better than I could in words. Regarding your first point, I din't address that because I didn't have anything interesting to say about that. The reason we require more than one person to vote to close a question is to ensure that there's some sort of checks-and-balances. Requiring a consensus of 3 users (it used to be 5, but was recently lowered to 3) helps ensure that questions are *correctly* closed. Lowering it to 1 would increase the false-positive rate.

Comment: Gentlemen, I use a real name and I am the one who felt targeted here. show cartoons to your kids, Merry Christmas with all due respect. Now who is the admin of this site?

Comment: @RahulChoudhary There is no one single admin.  Cody is an elected moderator, which aside from the Community Managers, or SE staff, is about as high as you can get on the ladder.  [Please familiarize yourself with that aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: @RahulChoudhary If you came across something really offensive, you should flag it. But if you felt not taken seriously by a user having a cartoon user image or a made up name, I am afraid you have to live with it. This is no social network; what counts is the quality of the posts. Please try to focus on that instead.

Comment: I don't understand your concern about people not using their real names, @Rahul. If it's *accountability* that you're worried about, have no fear: Users are fully accountable for their actions here, regardless of what name they choose to use. That name *is* their identity, and *all* of their actions are stamped/logged with it. I should also point out that having a question closed is not evidence of targeting. If you have a genuine concern about being targeted, please raise it via a moderator flag on the post. These are confidential, and we take them seriously. Merry Christmas to you as well!

Answer (score 9):

> just saw a question being "closed" by three individuals. The first individual is sufficient to make the point.

No, the first individual is not sufficient in regular close voting. Over the last 6 to 8 years, we have learned by observation that single individuals turn out to be fallible. We noticed that questions that were answerable got closed, leading to the inability for users to contribute a good answer to on-topic and answerable questions. In order to prevent these kind of mishaps, it was decided that more than one user needs to agree with closing a question. For a long time, we lived with the quorum being 5, but [recently that got reduced to 3 users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good).

This system has proven to be effective.

You'll also sometimes come across questions that are single-handedly closed by either gold tag badge holders (that is, users who are true subject matter experts in their tag) or users with diamonds (elected moderators and Stack Exchange staff).

> Please ensure people use their real names and pictures when talking to people.

This is my real name, and I'm really fuzzy.

Comment: Fuzzy Wuzzy was a bear, // Fuzzy Wuzzy had no hair, // Fuzzy Wuzzy wasn't fuzzy, // was he? ♫

Comment: Thank you Rene, Cody. Please present question solutions (closures) after the question, not above it with 3 persons. The response to the last question felt like a virtual brawl that i could'nt figure out were humans or bots; have an anti lynching in my state for even 2 folks trying to get on top on one, in the real world. hushaby, and the pretty little ponies. ♫

Comment: @RahulChoudhary the post notices moved to the top [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) so that ship has sailed.

Comment: Again, @Rahul, solutions and closures are completely different things. Please read [my answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392068) for details. As rene commented, a recent change was made to show the "closed" notices above the question, rather than below it, in order to make them more visible. Your and my feelings about the change aside, it isn't likely to change now. You can nevertheless weigh in with your thoughts on [the global Meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700). And, as stated above, if something appears to be a brawl, then flag it for a mod.

Comment: Who's Designed this site? It's a Helpdesk, not an Apiary; Get Real. We are all Sapiens here.

Comment: @RahulChoudhary If you want your comment to be seen by the one you're addressing it to, prefix it with the `@name` as you have seen us doing, and it will notify the person in question.