# Why is the close vote threshold for Meta still at 5?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

**TL;DR**: What is the reason the vote threshold is still 5 on Meta Stack Overflow and not 3?

---

So I was looking at some questions on meta, and I realized that it still takes 5 votes to close a question on meta. This struck me as odd, because [the threshold was recently changed to 3 on the main site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good?cb=1).

There is certainly no rule that says that the threshold for meta and the main site have to match, and I certainly don't object to them being different. Meta is much smaller than the main site, and is easier to moderate. However, I'm going to ask purely just out of curiosity: is there a reason the threshold wasn't changed on the meta site?

I have not been able to find a duplicate. The closest thing I could find was [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good?cb=1#comment743903_391832):

> Shouldn't the threshold be set to 3 on MSO as well? It currently looks like to not be the case, for example this question required 5 votes to be closed. – Tom 2 days ago

However, unless I'm missing something, it seems that this comment has been left unanswered. Given that this question is bound to come up again, I figured it was worth asking in its own question.

Is there a reason the vote threshold is still 5 on Meta Stack Overflow and not 3 like the main site?

Comment: SO traffic is far higher than traffic on any of the meta sites (including Meta SO), so having the exception of 3 votes apply only to SO and not to Meta SO nor anywhere else makes sense to me. The close moderation problems with main are not present here.

Comment: Because I can just hammer all of the questions on Meta? Seriously, do you see that there's a problem with questions not getting closed on Meta? I don't. Meta is a much lower-traffic site, like the other sites in the Stack Exchange network, which still have their close-vote threshold set to 5. I don't see why we need this on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray no problem here. Most questions on meta deserve to be open anyway. I was just curious about it, especially since the comment was unanswered, at least at the time of writing.

Comment: I think requiring 5 votes to close controversial posts on meta is excellent. The close vote review queue is nearly always empty, and questions tend to get closed fast enough

Comment: Also meta is sometimes controversial. 3 close votes would result more often in close/reopen wars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meta has a much higher active users / active posts ratio. Probably even higher if we only take users with close voting privileges.

On top of that, there is usually one or two mods lurking in the meta-shadows. For a site with the amount of post traffic we have is more than sufficient to handle the occasional stray question.

Closing and reopening questions is very rarely a problem in meta, and reducing the threshold would only make close/reopen "wars" more frequent.

While on main we used to enjoy a Close Votes review queue with more than 8000 questions, the queue here on meta is currently empty.

There is no need to reduce the number of required votes to close/reopen on meta. It's better to adjust these thresholds on each specific site instead of making the change universal.