# Reopen Queue Audit Bug

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

There is currently a bug in Reopen Queue audits. I haven't visited the review queues in quite some time and decided to go at it today and immediately noticed I was facing an audit because it still shows that it took 5 people to close [the audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25240683):

[image]

Obviously this isn't possible with the [vote-to-close threshold being reduced to 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/5781745).

So, can we fix these audits to reflect the current threshold system in place so the bad reviewers don't get a heads up that they are being audited?

Comment: If you notice that, you're probably not a bad reviewer.

Comment: The funny part is I was thinking the same thing when writing that line @TheWanderer.

Comment: Why do you think it  is "bug"? The goal of audit is achieved - the audit confirmed that you are paying attention. So far audits were considered good when a person who is somewhat aware of review guidances and somewhat paying attention can easily pass it (like in this case). Anything more nuanced  than that leads to tons of meta posts about questionable audits... The presence of tell-tale signs of an audit was never considered a problem...

Comment: Obviously, a question which was asked "10 days ago" would be closed by at most 3 people. However, it's certainly possible for questions which were closed by 5 people to enter the reopen queue. To [quote Shog9](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572): "[The question] will be enqueued once per reopen vote as long as there are no outstanding reopen votes that've already triggered a review." Thus, assuming that something is an audit *only* because 5 people closed it would be inaccurate. Obviously, with the additional information that it was closed recently, seeing 5 close voters does indicate an audit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)