# How useful is triaging of the question having two close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, triage, statistics

If a triaged question gets 2 close votes (within review or outside of it, doesn't matter) then an Unsalvageable->Needs Improvement review from 3K user will close it.

Closing questions is not how this queue was intended to work, it was originally supposed to merely [pass to appropriate specialized queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/839601):

> sort potentially-problematic posts into categories that can be routed elsewhere

That makes one wonder if at this point it makes better sense to pass the question from triage to close queue. I would like to get some statistics to better understand whether change like this would be reasonable or not. (This is not really straightforward idea because one can in principle argue in favor of keeping such questions in triage to give them chance to get to H&I and improve.)

Specifically, I would like to learn how many of the questions got a second vote to close while hanging in triage and how many of these managed to remain open (and not deleted).

I would prefer statistics for a period of 2-4 months, ideally for questions of age over 30 days (age constraint is there to account for the impact of 30-days autodeletion script).

Comment: I think triage having questions on the cliff of closing was not a big deal before [3 CV threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/839601) was introduced, because back then chances of a question to get 4 votes to close while still in triage were probably negligible

Comment: Other than the data request, I'm not sure what you're getting at here. Why does it matter where the close-votes come from? A close-vote (or flag) has just as much value if it's placed from within Triage, the CV queue, or not in a review queue at all. If the result of Triage is Unsalvageable, then the post will go into the CV queue, as it would anytime it got the close-flags or close-votes which are part of a user giving an "Unsalvageable" response. I don't know if the post getting an "Unsalvageable" result is even considered in moving into the CV queue, as the flags/votes would do that anyway.

Comment: @Makyen this primarily comes from my [prior study of the triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394747/839601). Back then I noticed that some close worthy questions that already had votes to close seem to be uselessly hanging in there for several hours (note such questions are blocked from getting to close queue). These felt like much better fit for close queue, not triage. Back then I had no time to chew it because I had other things to do but after a while I figured that there may be area for improvement and decided to learn more to find out whether it makes sense to proceed with it or not

Comment: ...specifically, if it turns out that stats show many questions with two close votes get stuck in triage and most of such questions don't improve then I plan to post a feature request to move such questions from triage to close queue (though frankly I would prefer opposite, ie that there would be too few such questions or their chance to improve would be reasonably high because that would relieve me from spending effort on feature request:)

Comment: My problem with that is that I don't see how it's helpful. As far as I know, questions don't get "stuck" in Triage, not really. The Triage queue runs through basically all of its questions relatively quickly. Where things do get stuck is in the close-vote queue. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61662683/timeline) took 4 hours 2 minutes to go through Triage with an "Unsalvageable" result. It then moved into the CV queue and spent more than *14 days* in the CV queue, but didn't get a single review. The problem in getting things closed isn't Triage, it's the CV queue.

Comment: @Makyen I understand that close queue is not quite efficient. But that doesn't look like a good reason to keep questions polluting inappropriate queue (that is, if stats show that it's indeed inappropriate and that there are enough such questions to bother - because without stats there is no way to know). As for your 4-hours example, it doesn't look like reasonably quick to me sorry. Not to mention that I have seen questions stuck in triage for twice as much