# Can I view close reasons on another user's closed question?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I don't *really* need to do this, but I'm curious.

After another user's question has been closed, I can (because I have sufficient rep) see *who* has voted to close, but not *why*. Is there a way I can as not-the-asker see the close reasons? For example:

[image]

My particular curiosity here is that I voted to close+migrate to CrossValidated, but the question doesn't seem to have migrated (so I assume that the other close-voters chose some other reason?)

With the usual apologies if I'm missing something obvious. (I have a vague memory that I used to see some information at least about the majority close-reason?)

Comment: The answer is you could, but first you have to procure a diamond.

Comment: that sounds like **way** more trouble than it's worth :-)

Comment: Strangely, on a pending close-vote, if you choose "a community-specific reason" you can't even check what you *yourself* chose by clicking "Close" again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a user with [close-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you actually *can* see the detailed reason why the question was closed as off-topic. The only exception to that is when the question is actually generically closed as off-topic. I'm 99.9% certain that's what happened for the one you're looking at.

There are two ways that a question can get closed as generically off-topic:

1. A quorum of users voted to close for "a community-specific reason" (formerly labeled "off-topic"), and then close the "other" sub-reason (you know, the one that gives you a textbox to type your custom reason into).

   The big blue box never displays this user-entered reason (because...yeah), so it just says that the question was closed as "off-topic". However, the system will automatically post a comment on behalf of the first user who voted to close the question for this custom reason, and that comment will contain the exact wording of the custom reason that they entered. For subsequent close-voters who chose the same reason, the system will automatically upvote that original comment.
2. Everyone voted to close the question as off-topic, but no consensus was reached. In other words, it was a split decision, with some close voters picking one off-topic reason and other close voters picking a different off-topic reason. (This is exactly what you proposed as the explanation in the question.)

   In that case, the system doesn't know which specific reason to pick for display in the big blue box, so it just falls back to a generic off-topic reason. In this case, I don't think there's any way that you, as a non-moderator, can see which specific off-topic reason that individual close-voters picked. I guess the idea is that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm surprised - I was the first close vote, and I closed because I thought it should be migrated to Cross Validated. Ben apparently did so as well (given he asked this question). That makes at least 2/3 of us voting that way... unless one of us is misremembering?

Comment: A "should be migrated" that doesn't reach a consensus will also appear as generically off-topic (case #2). I'm not sure which question is being referred to here.

Comment: Ah - I was assuming that "consensus" just meant a majority, but reading your #2 more closely I see it's a unanimous consensus. So presumably the third close voter picked a different reason than me and Ben.

Comment: @Gregor Well, I intentionally wrote that bit of my answer to avoid specifying whether the consensus was unanimous or not. :-) I had to go [look up what the current rules are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/). Previously, when 5 close-votes were required to effect a closure, migration could happen as long as 4 out of 5 close-voters proposed migration to the same site (supermajority). Now, with the close-vote threshold lowered to 3, it requires unanimous consensus to migrate. So, yes, you are right, but my answer doesn't say that because I didn't know at the time I wrote it.