# Drop vote-to-migrate threshold to 2 of the 3 VTC's?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, migration

As @Shog9 mentioned when [originally implementing 3-vote-close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/11810933):

> [Previously], migrating a question to another site require[d] that 4 of the 5 votes all agree that the question should be migrated to a specific site.
>
> As migration would be blocked otherwise, I'm also temporarily lowering the threshold for migration from 4 votes to 3 - essentially making a migration **require unanimous agreement from close voters.** (emphasis added)

When there's a good [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux)/[wsl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl2) question that would be suitable for Super User, I vote-to-migrate and toss a [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) into SOCVR as well, but usually these get closed by (I'm assuming) a single "Not about programming" vote. I know that my personal "muscle memory" often pushes me in the direction of an "Off-topic" vote when I should have at least *considered* migration.

Is there any reason that the bar couldn't/shouldn't be dropped to 2-votes-to-migrate?  This would keep intact the original spirit of allowing one "other" vote to not derail the migration.

Of course, votes-to-migrate *should* be carefully considered regardless.  Only *good*, suitable questions should be migrated. I'm not proposing that we lower the bar on the quality of questions that are migrated, just that we accept two voters opinions on the suitability.

Comment: Also happens fairly regularly with questions posted on the main site that are *about* the main site. So migrating to meta is appropriate, however, a single "Not about programming" or any other close reason blocks that.

Comment: What if a condition was added to vote for migrations where you should have a minimum amount of reputation on the other site? Maybe having the close votes privilege on the other site? This would ensure the person casting the vote has some knowledge about what questions would be on-topic and suitable for the other site.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I did consider that, but technically that's a much bigger implementation, of course.  I have gold-badge in the tag on Super User, but I can't imagine the cross-site work needed to check that.  I'm going for the simple case first ;-)

Comment: A *cheap* solution here might be for the system to raise an automatic mod flag if 2/3 close votes are for migration. That leaves the current system basically intact with some extra exception handling.

Comment: Wonder if you could adjust the threshold based on tag popularity too. More viewers = more voters and vice versa.

Comment: @Tanner I've always thought that "scaling" *might* be a good way to handle lower-volume tags.  That said, there are probably a lot of corner cases involved.  Regardless, it's definitely not an "easy" solution for an already-constrained SE dev staff ;-)

Comment: @VLAZ My first thought was that it would work.  But the corner-case there is that, at least at present, the flag queue is deep enough that the OP might have reposted already after it gets closed. That means that it would require additional effort for the Mod to check if the user had recently posted on the other site.  Also, the question would be *initially* closed regardless, so there's still the "negative reaction" (warranted or not) from the user that could be avoided by automatic vote-to-migrate.

Comment: @Tanner you'll quickly run into an issue trying to quantify what "popular" means. More questions? Some tags have less questions but more oversight because of it. More *views*? That is partly a function of quantity of questions. But also a tag with very few questions might get a disproportionate representation if it exists on a question with millions of views. Also - *views* do not account for how active the community is there. The views can be mostly from users already acting on the questions. Or from mostly anonymous users. Who knows.

Comment: @VLAZ "viewers" is probably the wrong term, but there would be some logical combination of metrics that would allow some form of weighting. Low traffic tags may never get to a higher threshold, where as higher traffic tag could easily surpass it.

Comment: Opinion: The only people who's migration votes should count are the voters who also have close vote privileges (and thus have demonstrated some understanding of what's acceptable) on the target site with the possible exception of migrate to meta.

Comment: @user4581301 While I agree that would probably be a better system, it's just not what's in place nor has ever been.  Even better - Just have a "Inbound Migrations" review queue, perhaps.  Two reviewers with enough rep on the target site (or one gold-badge in the tag) could vote to allow the migration.

Comment: How often do migrated questions prove worthy of the hassle to migrate them? What percentage of them garner upvotes/answers? Do other sites really want our junk? Where did meta questions with detailed statistics go?

Comment: @oguzismail We have no way of knowing the overall number unless SE provides statistics.  If migration isn't useful, then it's a feature that SE should just turn off entirely.  I'm going on the assumption that it was useful when it required 4 of 5 votes, and that it would still be useful today with 2 of 3.  The logic of a single vote derailing the migration just doesn't make sense. Also there's only a "hassle to migrate them" if the automatic vote fails - Then a Mod has to do it manually.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds re "we have no way of knowing" - [SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/997587). PostHistory has migration events (PostHistoryTypeId 35 and 36). then you can join on Posts / Votes / PostFeedback to get voting info, closure info, etc. [cross-site SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315533/997587) is a thing. in case you're wondering, I don't think info about aged-away migration votes is in SEDE (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/997587)).

Comment: 4/5 is not the same as 2/3. Migration not happening unless all close voters agree makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @user4581301 That would be an _extremely_ small pool of candidates. A more realistic criterion would be "someone who has an account on the target site and has earned reputation there", or perhaps earned the "Informed" badge on that site.

Comment: @TylerH Overly restrictive, yes, but if you do not know that the question will be well-received on Site X, you have no business migrating. Maybe as low as commenting privileges would be suitable, but I suspect a good minimum would be "able to access the review queues."

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think you need to have close vote privileges to know whether a question will be on-topic. Otherwise why are we letting _anyone_ ask a question on the site without first getting close vote reputation? Seems like a specious argument to me. As for "well-received", _no one_ can guess at that. There are perfectly good questions on all sites that are still closed, and vice versa.

Comment: That I'm not going to argue with. We've got folks with fantastic amounts of rep that are too fast on the draw (or don't draw fast enough) and rank n00bs that "get it" immediately. We should consider that there be no migration at all. The asker should be directed to the help center for a candidate site and told to rework the question to bring it in line with that site's rules and re-ask, then delete the off-topic question. If they do it, awesome. If they don't, the roomba will clean up the off-topic question in a few weeks.